# Python sockets: binding to '' vs socket.gethostname()

Tags: python, sockets, networking, port

What is the difference between binding a socket like this:

```
sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), 9999))
```

versus this:

```
sock.bind(('', 9999))
```

According to the HOWTO, binding to `socket.gethostname()` makes the socket visible to the outside world. However, it also says that binding to `''` makes the socket reachable by any address the machine happens to have. Does this mean that it also makes it reachable by the outside world? My guess is binding to `''` allows the socket to be reached both from within the same machine (through loopback) as well as from other machines, while binding to `socket.gethostname()` will only allow connections from other machines (**including the same machine**, but just not through the loopback interface). Please let me know if this is wrong. Also, if I am behind a router, will I still need to set up some sort of port forwarding in order to listen for connections from the internet with both of these binding methods? Or will binding to `''` allow me to directly listen for connections to my public ip? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding to `0.0.0.0` or `''` (aka "Wildcard Address" or INADDR_ANY) will bind to *all* interfaces, *including* public ones.

Binding to `127.0.0.1` ('localhost') will only bind to the loopback interface.

Binding to the specific IP address, as resolved from the result of `gethostname`, will only accept connections to the associated interface. (A connection made from the same machine must be made to the resolved IP, not the loopback.)

Routing / firewalls / forwarding is a separate issue as the listening socket is local to the machine, which must be exposed through network to the outside world: once the connection *gets* to machine the socket binding rules become relevant.

Comment: Can you expand on the last part? What does binding to `socket.gethostname()` actually do? What do you mean by 'the associated interface'?

Comment: `gethostname` returns the hostname of the machine. The hostname of the machine (type in `hostname` on the console) will in turn be resolved to an IP address. It is the IP address (and not the hostname itself) that the socket binds to.

Comment: Thanks. So if I want my socket to be accessible from the internet, I only need to bind to `''`, and I don't need to set up port forwarding or anything like that?

Comment: @SimonZhu Routing / firewalls / forwarding is a separate issue. This binding affects *only* the local socket binding on the machine. The interface itself must be exposed through network to the outside world: once the connection *gets* to machine the socket binding rules will take effect.

Comment: Alright. Last question (for clarification): `''` is effectively the same as `0.0.0.0`, right?

Comment: @SimonZhu Yes, it's the same.